# How to apply CSS to buttons?

Tags: css

I want apply CSS to all my buttons but not referencing all buttons id in my CSS stylesheet. How to proceed?

```
<button id="buttonEdit">Save</button>
```

I already try:

```
input[type=button]
{
    fonr-size: 80%;
}
```

but this doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have styles associated with the buttonEdit id in your CSS?

I've just copied in your button to a "Try It Yourself" area on W3Schools, and added my own style in the header

```
button { font-size: 80%; }
```

As everyone else has already posted, and it worked. I did a before test to see the button, then added the style & refreshed. Button text got smaller.

If there are no styles associated with buttonEdit that could be messing things up, then I'd triple check you didn't accidentally forget the colon after font-size.

Comment: I don't know why but I had to add '!important' in front of it. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
button, input[type=button]
{
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

The element is `button`, not `input`

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to a button, not an input field, so you should use the correct term in css.

```
button
{
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Then try changing your html and use `<input type="button" id="buttonEdit" value="Save">` and use the css from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using an `input` with `type="button"`, but a `button` element:

```
button
{
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and nasty fix is just to put `style="style:value;"` in every button tag.